# Spree API - Create Product Variant with Initial stock quantity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, spree, variant, stock

I'm trying to create a Variant with amount of initial stock, via the API in an application.

Example URL:

```
--post http://localhost:3000/api/products/apache-baseball-Jersey/variants/
```

I found no way to do this. I tried to pass the parameters:
variant [amount], stock_item [count_on_hand], etc.

In the Spree documentation, to create the "stock_item," you need to do a new request on **/api/stock_locations /1/stock_items**. But I want to make just one request.

It is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't send count_on_hand with one api request because we can manage our product stock on multiple locations so we need to manage this through one request per stock location that why it is required to send count_on_hand with another api request.